# How to extract Folder from Macrium Reflect Free and preserve timestamp? (Windows)

Tags: windows-7, backup, macrium

I would like to extract my C:\Users\Userprofile from my  diskimage.mrimg backup file
I mount the backup image file in Explorer (Windows 7).

I drag and drop the folder or any older on to my C: drive, but the folder  date is changed changed to present, filename timestamps are preserved.

Anyway to fix this?

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I would imagine if you want to preserve the file metadata you would have to restore the image to a disk.  Why do you want to preserve the file metadata?

Answer (score 2):

If you simply use Explorer drag & drop or the command *copy*, the date created is at *that* time. Use [*RoboCopy*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) to preserve the date/time stamps. [RoboCopy (Windows *Robust Copy*) is built into Windows 7](https://pureinfotech.com/how-to-use-robocopy-in-windows-7-robust-file-copy-tool-microsoft/) (and newer versions).

For example, if the mounted image is in G:, and you want to copy to C:\temp\ then enter the following in CMD:

```
robocopy G:\Users\<username> C:\temp\<username> /mir /copy:DAT /dcopy:DAT
```

The /mir switch mirrors the folder, /copy:DAT specifies copy *file* **D**ata, **A**ttributes and **T**imestamps and /dcopy:DAT specifies copy *folder* **D**ata, **A**ttributes and **T**imestamps.

This is also usually much faster than drag/drop or using *copy*.